# How do you insert into an SQLite JSON array without duplicates? (like a set)

Tags: sql, json, sqlite

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "carts" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "products"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
)
```

Where the `products` column contains text values representing JSON arrays of numbers like `[12,13,14]`, how can I insert a single item without duplicates?

**Examples**

Add `17` to `[12,13,14]` to give `[12,13,14,17]`.

Add `13` to `[12,13,14]` to give `[12,13,14]` (no change therefore duplicate avoided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this to be the easiest way:

1. Insert the item into the array using the standard function `json_insert`.

```
> SELECT json_insert('[12,13,14]','$[#]',13) AS tempArray
tempArray
[12,13,14,13]
```

2. Use the table-valued function `json_each` to break apart the array into a temporary table.

```
> SELECT * FROM (SELECT json_insert('[12,13,14]','$[#]',13) AS tempArray), json_each(tempArray)
tempArray   key value   type    atom    id  parent  fullkey path
[12,13,14,13]   0   12  integer 12  1       $[0]    $
[12,13,14,13]   1   13  integer 13  2       $[1]    $
[12,13,14,13]   2   14  integer 14  3       $[2]    $
[12,13,14,13]   3   13  integer 13  4       $[3]    $
```

3. Take only the `value` column (as the others are not needed).

```
> SELECT value FROM (SELECT json_insert('[12,13,14]','$[#]',13) AS tempArray), json_each(tempArray)
value
12
13
14
13
```

4. Use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

```
> SELECT DISTINCT value FROM (SELECT json_insert('[12,13,14]','$[#]',13) AS tempArray), json_each(tempArray)
value
12
13
14
```

5. Use the aggregation function `json_group_array` to combine the results in a JSON array text value.

```
> SELECT json_group_array(DISTINCT value) FROM (SELECT json_insert('[12,13,14]','$[#]',13) AS tempArray), json_each(tempArray)
json_group_array(DISTINCT value)
[12,13,14]
```

6. Stick this statement into an `UPDATE` statement, replacing the example array with a reference to the desired field.

```
UPDATE carts
SET product = (SELECT json_group_array(DISTINCT value) FROM (SELECT json_insert(carts.product,'$[#]',13) AS tempArray), json_each(tempArray))
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH
    new_product(id, product_id) AS (VALUES (1, 13)),
    new_records AS (
        SELECT carts.id, json_insert(carts.products, '$[#]', np.product_id) AS products
        FROM carts, new_product AS np
        WHERE carts.id = np.id
          AND NOT (carts.products like         np.product_id || ',%'
                OR carts.products like '%,' || np.product_id
                OR carts.products like '%,' || np.product_id || ',%')
    )
UPDATE carts SET products = new_records.products
FROM new_records
WHERE carts.id = new_records.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have a special JSON data type (although you can use it in the definition of a column).
All JSON-like values are strings (data type `TEXT`) and you can easily use string functions and the operator `LIKE` to check for a pattern in their values:

```
UPDATE carts
SET products = json_insert(products, '$[#]', ?)
WHERE id = 1
  AND REPLACE(REPLACE(products, '[', ','), ']', ',') NOT LIKE '%,' || ? || ',%';
```

Replace `?` with the value that you want to insert.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=f6dff30639a4db2c1c334542bb6b58c4).